# How can one view line-by-line code coverage in GitHub?

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a Node.js project, which includes Istanbul, a tool that can generate a code coverage report. I would like to see which lines are not covered and which are covered by tests in my GitHub Pull Requests for this project.

Istanbul allows me to see the coverage locally in the `coverage/lcov-report` directory, but I would like to see this the "Files Changed" tab of my Pull Requests in GitHub.

There are some tools that provide visual line-by-line coverage:

CodeCov does this, but requires that I upload a coverage report to their servers.

[Covaralls](https://coveralls.io/) does also, but requires that you give them access to your repository.
[image: Coveralls visual test coverage]

[Jest coverage report](https://github.com/ArtiomTr/jest-coverage-report-action) uses GitHub actions to add annotations, but cannot add visual indications (e.g. highlighting) of line-by-line test coverage.

[image]

Is there any other way to visualize line-by-line test coverage in a GitHub Pull Request?

Comment: This is not really the problem that GitHub is meant to solve. Since GitHub is really just a fancy web interface for Git, it doesn't care much about your code. Test coverage info like this is usually handled by a separate tool. Have you used Sonarqube? It will give you coverage and a lot more.

Comment: @Z4-tier Github has tons of commercial customers and *is* trying to solve problems like this, though it does so poorly for now

Comment: Sadly GitHub still does not support this as far as I can tell. Both [Gitlab](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/testing/test_coverage_visualization.html) and [Bitbucket](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1218271/code-coverage-for-bitbucket-server) support this. The best I can find for Github is [this action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/code-coverage-annotation-line-by-line) but the annotations make the PR unreadable.